# Modifying a property list

Tags: common-lisp, property-list

I have a [property list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_p.htm#property_list):

```
(setf *star* '(:points 5))
```

I'd like to modify this plist. Sometimes the better choice is to do mutation, and sometimes the better choice is to use an immutable update.

How to modify the plist using **mutation**?

```
(mutate *star* :points 6)
*star* ; '(:points 6)
```

And how to modify the plist using an **immutable update**?

```
(update *star* :points 6) ; '(:points 6)
*star*                    ; '(:points 5)
```

Comment: In this particular case, by quoting the list you create a literal object. Its modification has undefined consequences. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ga.htm

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for are [`getf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm) and maybe [`get-properties`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get_pr.htm). 
To modify the plist non-destructively, use [`list*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_list_.htm):

```
(setq *star* (list* :points 6 *star*))
```

If your plist is [associated with a symbol](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_4.htm), you should use [`get`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get.htm) and [`remprop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rempro.htm).

NB: it is a much better idea to use association lists (see [`assoc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_assocc.htm) and [`acons`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_acons.htm)) because they are more flexible (e.g., it is easier to switch from associating multiple objects with a key using alists).

Answer (score 2):

To mutate a plist, just use `setf`:

```
(setf (getf *star* :points) 59)
```

To do a non-mutative update, where the original value is left undisturbed, you might do something like this:

```
(defun update-plist (plist indicator new-value)
    (let ((other-properties nil))
      (loop while plist
            for property = (pop plist)
            for value = (pop plist)
            when (eq property indicator)
            do (return-from update-plist (list* property new-value
                                                (append other-properties plist)))
            else do (push value other-properties)
                    (push property other-properties))
      (list* indicator new-value other-properties)))
```

It differs from your example:

```
*star* ;; (:points 6 :color :green)
(update-plist *star* :points 5) ;; (:points 5 :color :green)
*star* ;; (:points 6 :color :green) -- Doesn't change.
```

Comment: This worked for me changing property value in `org-format-latex-options`